# Android Studio get shared file, name of Uri, from whatsapp to my app

Tags: android, kotlin, whatsapp

I use `android.intent.action.SEND`  I get file uri from Extra_stream (from whatsapp shared) but not include file name or extension. How can get file extension and file name?

```
    if (action == "android.intent.action.SEND") {
(intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as? Uri)?.let {

    Log.d("file path",it.path.toString())

}
```

Logcat
`D/file path:: /item/1dcbc1eb-ed83-4a9d-bddb-9effbca0b3ee`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem in the past, thankfully I found the answer from StackOverflow but I do not have a link to that answer now, so I am sharing the code that I am using.

this method will give you the file name from `uri`,

This function is in java:

```
    public static String getNameFromContentUri(Context context, Uri contentUri){  
                              Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
                              int nameColumnIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                              returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                              String fileName = returnCursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
                              return fileName;
}
```

and you can get a full path with this function,

This functions is in Kotlin:

```
companion object {
@JvmStatic
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val isKitKat: Boolean = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                return if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
                } else { // non-primary volumes e.g sd card
                    var filePath = "non"
                    //getExternalMediaDirs() added in API 21
                    val extenal = context.externalMediaDirs
                    for (f in extenal) {
                        filePath = f.absolutePath
                        if (filePath.contains(type)) {
                            val endIndex = filePath.indexOf("Android")
                            filePath = filePath.substring(0, endIndex) + split[1]
                        }
                    }
                    filePath
                }
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                var contentUri: Uri? = null
                if ("image" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("video" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                } else if ("audio" == type) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                }
                val selection = "_id=?"
                val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
                        split[1]
                )
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
            }
        } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
        } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return uri.path
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?,
                              selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(
                column
        )
        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri!!, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null)
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(column_index)
            }
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
    }

}
```

for java:

```
   public static String getFullPathFromContentUri(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    
            final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
    
            // DocumentProvider
            if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
                // ExternalStorageProvider
                if ("com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];
    
                    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                    }//non-primary e.g sd card
                     else {

                           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
                    //getExternalMediaDirs() added in API 21
                    File extenal[] = context.getExternalMediaDirs();
                   for (File f : extenal) {
                    filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    if (filePath.contains(type)) {
                        int endIndex = filePath.indexOf("Android");
                        filePath = filePath.substring(0, endIndex) + split[1];
                    }
                }
             }else{
                    filePath = "/storage/" + type + "/" + split[1];
             }
            return filePath;
        }
                }
                // DownloadsProvider
                else if ("com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
    
                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
    
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }
                // MediaProvider
                else if ("com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];
    
                    Uri contentUri = null;
                    if ("image".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    }
    
                    final String selection = "_id=?";
                    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                            split[1]
                    };
    
                       Cursor cursor = null;
                       final String column = "_data";
                       final String[] projection = {
                          column
                        };
       
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
            return null;
                }
            }
            // MediaStore (and general)
            else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
            }
            // File
            else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                return uri.getPath();
            }
    
            return null;
        }

    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                     String[] selectionArgs) {
    
            Cursor cursor = null;
            final String column = "_data";
            final String[] projection = {
                    column
            };
    
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
            return null;
        }
```